# Dynamically create JSON object using JSON Path in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, .net-5

I have a list of key-value pair of json property path and its value,

```
Key: $.orderNumber                                      Value: "100001"
Key: $.orderedOn                                        Value: "01-01-2021"
Key: $.product.name                                     Value: "hard"
Key: $.product.type                                     Value: "plastic" 
Key: $.contacts[?(@.contactType == 'primary')].phone    Value: "101010101010" 
Key: $.contacts[?(@.contactType == 'secondary')].phone  Value: "2020202020"
```

and wanted to create a JSON object or JSON string like below

```
{
  "orderNumber": "100001",
  "orderedOn": "01-01-2021",
  "product": {
    "type": "hard",
    "name": "plastic"
  },
  "contacts": [
    {
      "contactType": "primary",
      "phone": "101010101010"
    },
    {
      "contactType": "secondary",
      "phone": "202020202020"
    }
  ]
}
```

is it possible to create a JSON object using JSON PATH or  I need to check the write all properties manually?

I wanted to create JSON objects dynamically.

I have tried the Json.net Unflatten but it is not covering the conditional array key.

Comment: Are you using .Net or .Net-Core?

Comment: Been asked a few times but it's not implemented out of the box in Json.NET.  Along with the question linked by gunr2171, see [how to set the value of a json path using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17455052/3744182), [Json.Net, how to create json dynamically by path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44076294/3744182) and a few others if I recall correctly.  And actually converting `[?(@.contactType == 'primary')]` to an object with a `"contactType": "primary"` property looks nontrivial.

Comment: @Amy yes, I am using .Net 5

Comment: @dbc both of the link does not resolve my problem.

Comment: I know.  As I said, it's unfortunately not implemented out of the box, and nobody ever posted a custom implementation here.   Looks like somebody closed your question as a duplicate of [Build JObject from JSONPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43988405/3744182), to which the accepted answer is **No.**.  So on the one hand your question is a duplicate but on the other hand the answer given is kind of useless.  Do you need this reopened in case somebody wants to write all the code required to parse a JSONPath and populate a JObject from it?

Comment: @dbc how do I reopen the question, I have used the unflatten of json.net and that is useful but it cannot cover he conditional JSON path for an array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build JObject from JSONPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988405/build-jobject-from-jsonpath)

Comment: @UmairAnwaar reopening the question isn't going to change the answer, it's still no. You do now have `System.Text.Json` in .Net5 which pretty much superceeds Json.Net(ish). But I don't know if that supports this or not. My gut feeling is it won't as this seems a bit niche. You'll likely have to write a solution yourself. Which [this answer tells you how to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43991519/542251)

Comment: @Liam thanks for the suggestion, I had to write the custom solution which is not dynamic.